# How to hit the URLs automatically and put the received response into a csv file?

Tags: php

I've an .csv file which contains hundreds of URLs. I've to write a PHP script which will read the file then loop through all the URLs. 
       In the loop each URL should automatically hit(like we type the URL in browser's address bar and press enter button), the response received after hitting the URL has to be written into a new .csv or .txt file in the following way:

```
 Request URL, Response received
```

At the end of loop each request URL and its respective response should be written to a .txt or .csv file. The response is surely going to be in the csv format in one liner. So no validation is required while writing the response to the file.
    I did lot of search on google on it, but couldn't get the useful solution. Could anyone help me to solve this issue? 
    Thanks in Advance.

Comment: show us what you have written so far.

Comment: Hi, this is more a project description than a question. Do you have a specific technical issue that you are having?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes, my issue is I don't know how to hit the URLs automatically and get the response.

Comment: Google `php load url` -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will probably find the following functions useful :

- [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)() to read a CSV file (the one containing the list of URLs)
- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)() to "hit" a URL
- [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)() to write the results in a CSV file

Look at PHP Manual to get details on how to use these functions but they are pretty "basic"